# How to unregister a token from firebase?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm doing an app for ionic 2 and I'm trying to unregister a token from firebase. I'm using **"cordova-plugin-firebase"** to use my push notifications, the problem is, if I user logout in a device and login with another account on the same device, they both will have the same token, so he may receive notifications that he shouldn't.

Any way to do this?
For what I have see, what I have is a unsubscribe for a topic, but I'm not using topics, I got my own database saving the users and tokens.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you post your database? The part where you save the user tokens

Comment: Well, I do it from a POST, the columns are: id, username, DeviceID, Token, LastLogin

Comment: what I could do is, if some user contains that token, I just remove it from him... But that could load my webservice and database if I got to many logins at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do it from POST, you can do this on your post method:

```
logoutFctn(){
  let header = { // YOUR HEADERS };
  let body = {
    "token": null,
    "deviceId": null
  };
  let url = 'url/to/user';

  this.http.post(url, body, headers //or options).subscribe(response =>{
    // HERE YOU DO THE LOGOFF FROM FIREBASE, after setting the user tokens and device id to null, 
    // that'll remove then from the user node.
    // DO THE REST OF YOUR CODE
  });
};
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Well, I was loggin for another way, using the plugin to unregister the token like there is for unsubscribe a topic...
But I guess that I will do it this way...
Thank you for the help